# How do I best handle data in my application

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, ienumerable

Working on a C# application for Payroll.  As a warning, I'm very new to all this, just been chucked in to it and enjoying it but it's a lot to absorb in a short amount of time.  I'm currently learning about LINQ and classes.  I'm grabbing invoice lines out of our account SQL server and paying personnel based on sales and some situations that can be determined from the data.  See the sample below:

```
Ord_Inv_No      Delivery_Date       Trmnl_Key   TrmnlGrp_Key
INV-00059754    2016-05-02 07:00:00 23          3
INV-00059839    2016-05-02 16:01:00 56          3
```

This is a very small portion of the data but it gives the gist of what I want to analyze.  I have a class as shown below:

```
class SalesItem
{

    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public DriverData DriverData { get; set; }
    public int TerminalKey { get; set; }
    public int TerminalGroupKey { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string CustomerLocation { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerLocationKey { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCredited { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    public string TermianlGroupDesc { get; set; }

    public SalesItem(string driverName, int terminalKey, int terminalGroupKey, string deliveryDate, 
        string customerLocation, int? customerLocationKey, bool? isCredited, string invoiceNumber, string terminalGroupDesc)
    {
        this.DriverName = driverName;
        this.TerminalKey = terminalKey;
        this.TerminalGroupKey = terminalGroupKey;
        this.DeliveryDate = deliveryDate;
        this.CustomerLocation = customerLocation;
        this.CustomerLocationKey = customerLocationKey;
        this.IsCredited = isCredited;
        this.InvoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.TermianlGroupDesc = terminalGroupDesc;
    }
```

I'm trying to implement a way I can 1. store each `SalesItem` (each row) as a Collection for lack of a better word.  I want to iterate through the collection of `SalesItem` and find out a few things, like when an Invoice row shows up twice with a different `Trmnl_Key` and two different `Ord_Inv_No` that have the exact same Date as one another and return the greatest rate of pay for the two.  I had written some logic for this that was manipulating a `DataTable` that I was grabbing through SQLConnection/Command/Reader/Etc but all of this was very slow and cumbersome when dealing with a week of data and I couldn't get the comparison to work reliably.  Further down the line, these rows would be flagged in a DataGrid in WPF for human verification of their pay in case of something funky coming in from the accounting software.

Right now, I'm trying to save the collection as shown below (which is just the current iteration, I have several days worth of trying that's failed.)

```
 private void GetInformation(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox currentItem = sender as ComboBox;
        int driverKey = Convert.ToInt32(currentItem.SelectedValue);
        DriverData driver = new DriverData();
        driver.SetDriverData(driverKey);
        int years = driver.ServiceYears;
        List<SalesItem> items =  (from o in transportationDb._Payroll_Orders
                                 where o.Ord_Driver_Key == driverKey &&
                                 o.Delivery_Date >= new DateTime(2016, 5, 2) && o.Delivery_Date <= new DateTime(2016, 5, 8)
                                 select new SalesItem(
                                     o.Driver_Name,
                                     o.Trmnl_Key,
                                     o.TrmnlGrp_Key,
                                     o.Delivery_Date.ToString(),
                                     o.CustLoc_Description,
                                     o.Ord_CustLoc_Key,
                                     o.Credits, o.Ord_Inv_No, o.TrmnlGrp_Description )).ToList();


        dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

    }
```

Any wisdom or direction would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: you would need to declare `List<SalesItem> items` outside the scope of the GetInformation method at the class level also are you seeing the items in the dataGrid after you assign the ItemsSource perhaps you should google how to Bind a List<T> to a DataGridView.. and look at using it's DataSource property

Comment: EF is not performant.  Use TSQL and DataReader.

Comment: @Paparazzi If you wanted performance, wouldn't you just use stored procedure?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth If you want to write a sp for each case.  I would still use TSQL and DataReader even if I did have some sp.

Comment: @MethodMan Right now I'm getting a runtime error that the cast is invalid in the debugger.  IDE (Visual Studio Community) does not give me an error.  I can bind if all I declare is `var items = *my query here*` but that doesn't seem to allow my manipulation after the data is retrieved.

Comment: @paprazzi I've been racking my brain and google for a way to write this as a sp for SQL's speed, but has as of yet come up empty.  I can make the logic happen pretty easily in C# though.  If you have any resource you could point me to, I'd be thrilled to check it out.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827984/Generically-Populate-List-of-Objects-from-SqlDataR

Comment: @Paparazzi EF isn't the fastest, but it is rarely the cause of things being "too slow".  It's usually a problem with the data structure, or a N+1 query, or similar.  You can always switch to dapper if it turns out to actually be the bottleneck, but it rarely is.

Comment: @RobertMcKee I don't have a question.   And I have seen some very slow and very ugly stuff come out of EF.

Comment: Well, the OP in his question already stated that he is retrieving a list, and then doing processing on it, which is likely a much better bottleneck than the method in which he is using to retrieve the data, and EF makes generating such queries so much easier that it'll likely outperform the same task with TSL/Datareader and then processing client side.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this isn't much different than what you had, but try this and see if it works for you:

```
private void GetInformation(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox currentItem = sender as ComboBox;
    int driverKey = Convert.ToInt32(currentItem.SelectedValue);
    DriverData driver = new DriverData();  //What's this for?
    driver.SetDriverData(driverKey); //What's this for?
    int years = driver.ServiceYears; //What's this for?
    var startDate=new DateTime(2016, 5, 2);
    var endDate=new DateTime(2016, 5, 8);
    var items = transportationDb._Payroll_Orders
      .Where(o=>o.Ord_Driver_Key == driverKey)
      .Where(o=>o.Delivery_Date >= startDate && o.Delivery_Date <= endDate)
      .Select(o=>new SalesItem {
        DriverName=o.Driver_Name,
        ...
      });
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

If your Orders table has an index on Ord_Driver_key and Delivery_Date, then this query should be pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps in some way. I'm not too sure of what you're trying to achieve. A save function could look something like the following, but I don't know exactly what kind of connection you're using. Note that I'm checking to make sure the record doesn't exist already.

```
 private void Save(SalesItem item)
    {
        if(!transportationDb._Payroll_Orders.Any(p => p.Ord_Inv_No == item.InvoiceNumber))
        {
            transportationDb._Payroll_Orders.Add(item.PayrollOrder);
            transportationDb.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            // Already exists
        }
    }
```

Update your class to however you'd like, but I'd do it this way from the limited knowledge of what your object is suppose to look like.

```
class SalesItem
{

    public SalesItem(_Payroll_Orders po == null, DriverData dd == null)
    {
        this._Payroll_Order = po != null ? po : new _Payroll_Orders();
        this.DriverData = dd != null ? dd : new DriverData();
    }

    private _Payroll_Orders _Payroll_Order { get; set; }

    public _Payroll_Orders PayrollOrder
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order; }
        set { _Payroll_Order = value; }
    }

    public string DriverName 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Driver_Name; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Driver_Name= value; }
    }
    public DriverData DriverData { get; set; }
    public int TerminalKey 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Trmnl_Key; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Trmnl_Key= value; }
    }
    public int TerminalGroupKey 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.TrmnlGrp_Key; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.TrmnlGrp_Key= value; }
    }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Delivery_Date; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Delivery_Date= value; }
    }
    public string CustomerLocation 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.CustLoc_Description; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.CustLoc_Description = value; }
    }
    public int? CustomerLocationKey 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Ord_CustLoc_Key; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Ord_CustLoc_Key = value; }
    }
    public bool? IsCredited 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Credits; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Credits = value; }
    }
    public string InvoiceNumber 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.Ord_Inv_No; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.Ord_Inv_No = value; }
    }
    public string TermianlGroupDesc 
    {
        get { return _Payroll_Order.TrmnlGrp_Description; }
        set { _Payroll_Order.TrmnlGrp_Description = value; }
    }
}
```

then you can change your function here so you only have to select 'new SalesItem(o, driver)':

```
 private void GetInformation(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox currentItem = sender as ComboBox;
        int driverKey = Convert.ToInt32(currentItem.SelectedValue);
        DriverData driver = new DriverData();
        driver.SetDriverData(driverKey);
        int years = driver.ServiceYears;
        List<SalesItem> items =  (from o in transportationDb._Payroll_Orders
                                 where o.Ord_Driver_Key == driverKey &&
                                 o.Delivery_Date >= new DateTime(2016, 5, 2) &&
                                 o.Delivery_Date <= new DateTime(2016, 5, 8)
                                 select new SalesItem(o, driver)).ToList();

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = items;

    }
```

Comment: thanks, I don't have time to look it over at the moment, but I will in a few hours.